# C++11 reverse iterator with while loop

Tags: c++, list, c++11, iterator, reverse-iterator

I know the code isn't good practice, so the question is not about that. I just want to understand how the following example works. Notice I don't do anything with the iterator when I call remove, so when the loop goes to the next iteration how is it pointing to the next element?

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Obj;
std::list<Obj> objs;

class Obj
{
public:
  Obj(const std::string& name, int age)
  : name_(name), age_(age)
  {}

  std::string name()
  {
    return name_;
  }

  int age()
  {
    return age_;
  }
private:
  std::string name_;
  int age_;
};


void remove(const std::string& name)
{
  auto it = find_if(objs.begin(), objs.end(),[name] (Obj& o) { return (o.name() == name); });
  if (it != objs.end())
  {
    std::cout << "removing " << it->name() << std::endl;
    objs.erase(it);
  }
}

int main()
{
  objs.emplace_back("bob", 31);
  objs.emplace_back("alice", 30);
  objs.emplace_back("kevin", 25);
  objs.emplace_back("tom", 45);
  objs.emplace_back("bart", 37);
  objs.emplace_back("koen", 48);
  objs.emplace_back("jef", 23);
  objs.emplace_back("sara", 22);

  auto it = objs.rbegin();
  while (it != objs.rend())
  {

   std::cout << it->name() << std::endl;

   if (it->name() == "tom")
   {
      remove(it->name()); //notice I don't do anything to change the iterator
   }
   else
   {
     ++it;
   }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Following is the output:

```
sara
jef
koen
bart
tom
removing tom
kevin
alice
bob
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour because you alter the list which invalidates all iterators. Also please don't use global variables.

Comment: @Swordfish "*you alter the list wich invalidates all iterators*" - No it doesn't; ["References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase).

Comment: @DanielLangr it does and becomes invalid. Sorry for the wrong wording of my previous comment, not \*all\* iterators become invalid.

Comment: @Swordfish Ye, only the one removed, though it's being referenced at the next step, so it's enough.

Comment: @luk32 "so it's enough" what is that supposed to mean? after `remove(it->name());` accessing it by `it->name()` is undefined behaviour. Strictly also `it != objs.rend()` is.

Comment: It's enough invoke UB. I meant it doesn't have to invalidate everything. Invalidating the element which is meant to go away is enough to invoke UB. I find it way more subtle than breaking "whole container" (i.e. all iterators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My other answer was not right. The observed behaviour is due to the implementation of `reverse_iterator`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator):

> `std::reverse_iterator` is an iterator **adaptor** that reverses the direction of a given iterator. In other words, when provided with a bidirectional iterator, `std::reverse_iterator` produces a new iterator that moves from the end to the beginning of the sequence defined by the underlying bidirectional iterator.
>
> For a reverse iterator `r` constructed from an iterator `i`, the relationship `&*r == &*(i-1)` is always true (as long as `r` is dereferenceable); thus a reverse iterator constructed from a one-past-the-end iterator dereferences to the last element in a sequence.

(emphasis mine). See also [[reverse.iterator]](http://eel.is/c++draft/reverse.iterators).

OK, what this means for us: when a reverse iterator `it` points to "tom", it actually wraps around a forward iterator to the *next* element, "bart". When you derefer it, it takes an element preceding the wrapped iterator, i.e., one before "bart", which indeed is "tom".

When you remove "tom", the wrapped iterator does not change. (Neither it is invalidated.) It still points to "bart". When you derefer the reverse iterator, it looks for what precedes "bart", which *now* is "kevin".

This means you don't really cause undefined behaviour. You would if you called `remove("bart")` at line 60.

Answer (score 3):

You *invalidate* the iterator by removing the object it addresses (regardless of whether you *use* the value of it for that purpose). If you try to access it after that, the behaviour is undefined (read: anything can happen, like the same `it` jumping to the next element, or your program crashing). You can't rely on this on any other behaviour.

Comment: Ok, I get that it is invalidated. Could you elaborate on 'like the same it jumping to the next element'. How would this happen if it is invaled? I have tested this for over a 100000 times and the next iteration always just prints "kevin" which is the next element.

Comment: That was just a rephrasal of what you said (or observed) happened. It's not an example I came up with.

Comment: I don't know much about the behavior of invalidated iterators. If it is invalid shouldn't it be similar like calling a function on a nullptr or is that a wrong assumption?

Comment: calling an invalid iterator is undefined behaviour. In your case the implementation of your standard library happens to leave the iterator pointing at the correct item so works but you can' t rely on that.

Comment: Don't make _any_ assumption, @rinn. There is no deterministic behaviour. It's pure chance that comes down to how the container and iterators happen to be implemented, or what's in your memory, or how many cats are within your city's official limits. Just code to spec and don't worry about it.

Comment: Iterator invalidation rules: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6438086/560648